# Android Drag and Drop between dialog and fragment

Tags: android, dialog, drag-and-drop, fragment

is it possible to drag view from Dialog to fragment ?

I have fragment, where I can open a dialog with some list items. I want to click on item, and drag, cancel the dialog, and then drag this item to my previous fragment.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure we can drag and drop elements but not sure why not from dialog to fragment

See if this library helps.

https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid

Comment: Well, I'm using native drag and drop interface, but when I click on item in Dialog, i can see it started dragging, but i cannot drop this item, everytime i get "Reporting drop result = false". It seems like draggig item doesn't see my drag location layout. But when i try to drag and drop from fragment to same fragment it works pretty good. Any ideas ?